# JupyterHub custom DockerSpawner to bind different shared volumes based on LDAP group membership

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab, docker-volume, jupyterhub

Users and groups are managed by LDAPAuthenticator.

```py
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'ldapauthenticator.LDAPAuthenticator'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.allowed_groups = [...]
....
```

DockerSpawner is currently used to bind shared and individual volumes e.g

```py
c.DockerSpawner.volumes = { 'jupyterhub-user-{username}': os.path.join(notebook_dir, 'MyNotebooks'),
                            'notebook-data': {'bind': os.path.join(notebook_dir, 'SharedData'), 'mode': 'ro'},
                            'deployment_shared-notebooks': {'bind': os.path.join(notebook_dir, 'SharedNotebooks'), 'mode': 'ro'}
                            }
```

This way the volumes are mounted for all the user from c.LDAPAuthenticator.allowed_groups.
I've found a snippet here (https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner/issues/239) showing how to make custom Spawner to mount volumes based on the username:

```py
from dockerspawner import DockerSpawner
class MyDockerSpawner(DockerSpawner):
    team_map = {
        'username1': 'team-a',
        'username2': 'team-b',
        'username3': 'team-a',
    }

    def start(self):
        if self.user.name in self.team_map:
            team = self.team_map[self.user.name]
            # add team volume to volumes
            self.volumes['/directory/jupyterhub-team-{}'.format(team)] = {
                'bind': '/home/jovyan/teamfolder',
                'mode': 'rw',  # or ro for read-only
            }
        return super().start()
```

How can a similar functionality be achieved based on LDAP user groups? e.g. only mount an additional specific volume when a user is a memember of `cn=certificateAdmin,ou=groups`